# Borrar campos de un Formulario luego de Confirmar envio con AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html5, ajax, formularios

Hola amigos buenas noches, requiero su apoyo en lo siguiente.

Estoy creando un formulario de contacto HTML5 usando JS y validando el envío mediante AJAX.

Lo que necesito es que al enviarse el formulario se actualice al cabo de unos 5 segundos de manera que los campos y el formulario en sí quede original.

**Acá mi form HTML**

```
        <form method="post" class="contacto">
    <fieldset>
        <div><label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" class="nombre" name="nombre" /></div>
        <div><label>Email:</label><input type="text" class="email" name="email" /></div>
        <div><label>Telefono:</label><input type="text" class="telefono" name="telefono" /></div>
        <div><label>Asunto:</label><input type="text" class="asunto" name="asunto" /></div>
        <div><label>Mensaje:</label><textarea cols="30" rows="5" class="mensaje" name="mensaje" ></textarea></div>
        <div class="ultimo">
            <img src="ajax.gif" class="ajaxgif hide" />
            <div class="msg" id="msg"></div>
            <button class="boton_envio">Enviar Mensaje</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

**Acá mi ajax**

```
(function(){
$(".boton_envio").click(function() {

    var nombre = $(".nombre").val();
        email = $(".email").val();
        validacion_email = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/;
        telefono = $(".telefono").val();
        mensaje = $(".mensaje").val();

    if (nombre == "") {
        $(".nombre").focus();
        alert('Por favor ingresa tu nombre');
        return false;
    }
    else if(email == "" || !validacion_email.test(email)){
        $(".email").focus();   
        alert('Por favor ingresa tu eMail');
        return false;
    }else if(telefono == ""){
        $(".telefono").focus();
        alert('Por favor ingresa tu número telefónico');
        return false;
    }else if(mensaje == ""){
        $(".mensaje").focus();
        alert('Por favor ingresa tu mensaje');
        return false;
    }else{
        $('.ajaxgif').removeClass('hide');
        var datos = 'nombre='+ nombre + '&email=' + email + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&mensaje=' + mensaje;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "proceso.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function() {
                $('.ajaxgif').hide();
                $('.msg').text('Mensaje enviado, pronto será contactado!').addClass('msg_ok').animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);  
            },
            error: function() {
                $('.ajaxgif').hide();
                $('.msg').text('Error, verifique los datos!').addClass('msg_error').animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);                 
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

**acá dejo el php donde lo proceso**

```
if($nombre != '' && $email != '' && $telefono != '' && $mensaje != ''){
mail($dest,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers); //ENVIAR!
```

}
?>

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> o que necesito es que al enviarse el formulario se actualice al cabo de unos 5 segundos de manera que los campos y el formulario en sí quede original.

Con `window#setTimeout` puedes ejecutar una tarea en un tiempo futuro. Ésta función recibe un callback con la tarea a ejecutar y un tiempo a ejecutarse especificado en milisegundos.

```
success: function() {
  $('.ajaxgif').hide();
  $('.msg')
    .text('Mensaje enviado, pronto será contactado!')
    .addClass('msg_ok')
    .animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);

  // se ejecutará en 5 segundos
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    var form = document.querySelector('form.contacto');
    form.reset();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Yo no lo haría en 5 segundos, si no inmediatamente luego de haberse completado la petición.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la prontitud de tu ayuda.

*acá dejo como lo coloqué y no me actualiza el form una vez del envío exitoso*

```
success: function() {
                $('.ajaxgif').hide();
                $('.msg')
                .text('Mensaje enviado, pronto será contactado!')
                .addClass('msg_ok')
                .animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);

                 // se ejecutará en 5 segundos
                  window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('form.contacto').reset();
                  }, 5000);

            },
            error: function() {
                $('.ajaxgif').hide();
                $('.msg').text('Error, verifique los datos!').addClass('msg_error').animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);                 
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

});
```

})();

Comment: No respondas para comentar. En su lugar, edita tu pregunta cuando quieras añadir información. He actualizado mi respuesta, mírala que he corregido el error.

Comment: Gracias @guzgarcia justo lo que necesitaba, con el ultimo arreglo pude lograr lo que buscaba.